# no rule to make target Qt-5-12.4/lib/libQt5Quick.a

Tags: qt, compilation, static, qt-quick, failed-installation

I compiled qt static using

```
..\configure -debug-and-release -static -opensource -opengl desktop -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

for testing purposes, and then created a simple Qml standard file.
By compiling with this static version, compiler complains and gives no rule to make target C:/Qt/Qt-5.12.4/lib/libQt5Quick.a
the file does not exist
What is wrong?

when compiling with 5.13 which is dynamic linked, it works fine.